# SQL foreign key error?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS userRole;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS account;

  CREATE TABLE account (
     lionID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     firstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     hashedpass VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (lionID)
   );


   CREATE TABLE roles (
     roleID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
     lionID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     administrator BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT False,
     qRole VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (roleID),
     FOREIGN KEY (lionID) REFERENCES account(lionID)
   );
```

I am having trouble understanding why I am getting an error..  the foreign key lionID in roles is referencing the primary key lionID in account but it doesn't seem to like it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 76: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY lionID REFERENCES account lionID'
)' at line 8
```

Comment: pls post other sql queries as well, i don't see course table here

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Your code is fine:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c83505.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in create statement:

You need to use Syntax:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_account`
        FOREIGN KEY (lionID) REFERENCES account(lionID)
```